# Can the Livecode browser widget display multiple tabs?

Tags: browser, tabs, widget

I am interesting automating the downloading of the full text of US patents from the US Patent & Trademark Office. That used to be possible until the office replaced their previous system with their new Patent Public Search system. With the current system, the following URL will result in two tabs, one of which is empty, and the second contains several windows, one of which contains the full text of the patent:

https://ppubs.uspto.gov/pubwebapp/external.html?q=10234567.pn.&db=uspat (10234567 is a patent number of interest)

Is there any way to get the browser widget to display that second tab through which a Livecode script can save the text of the patent? The idea is to give the LC stack a list of patent numbers through which the full text of each patent can be saved separately.

Created a stack with a browser widget, and set the URL of the browser widget to the URL that I described. I was hoping to see both tabs displayed, but got nothing.